# How to install virtual display in windows server 2016?

Tags: virtual-machine, multiple-monitors, display-settings, display-driver

I have VPS with Server 2016. I need to extend my desktop. Max resolution is 2560x1600 but I need more. Is it possible to add virtual monitor so I can extend my desktop? Tried Virtual display manager - didn't help. It splits my screen but doesn't add second display. Same with dfmirage and zonescreen, they add additional display adapter but not monitor. 
Also tried to add additional monitor through "add legacy hardware" in device manager, but when I chose any monitor driver folder windows shows that there is no driver.